# NCLOB to VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle, nclob

I am trying to convert a NCLOB to VARCHAR2 in Oracle, but get the following error:

> ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion
>   (actual: 2669, maximum: 2000)

Here is the code that I am using:

```
select substr(TO_NCHAR(NCLOB_FIELD),1,3800)
from TABLE
```

Any way around this error?

Comment: What do you not understand? Max. length of NVARCHAR2 is 2000 characters which is exceeded.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: yes, but do you have any suggestion on how to bypass this restriction?

Comment: No, a NVARCHAR2 must not be longer than 2000 - why do you think you can bypass it? btw, why do you try to convert a NCLOB to NVARCHAR2 at all?

Comment: I will be "reading" the data with a tool, that cannot "read" from NCLOB, which is why I would like to replace the NCLOBs with VARCHAR2, even though the text will be truncated.
btw, as per this doc, the max len of VARCHAR2 is 4000 [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330)

Comment: It might be 4000 Bytes which is 2000 characters for Multibyte NCLOB where each character uses at least 2 Bytes. Did you try `substr(TO_NCHAR(NCLOB_FIELD),1,1000)`?

Comment: yes, I did try it. The error kicks in before the SUBSTR at the TO_NCHAR function part, so even `substr(TO_NCHAR(NCLOB_FIELD),1,1)` gives an error...

Comment: Have you checked out the DBMS_LOB package?

Comment: @BrianLeach: yes, the DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR work for my CLOB fields, but does not seem to work for the NCLOB. I get the following error:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `SUBSTR` before the conversion and use a smaller size:

```
select TO_NCHAR(substr(NCLOB_FIELD,1,2000))
from TABLE;
```